# @Html.RadioButtonFor boolean

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Ive got a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Buy", "Keys", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="calc_steps">
    <div class="NumberedRow one">
        1.  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PaymentSystem, Model.PaymentSystems, new { @class = "calcsteps_select styledselect" })
    </div>
    <div class="NumberedRow two">
        2. <div class="cnt">
            Укажите тип лицензии
            <div class="radio-jquery-ui">@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsElite, "false") <label>Обычная</label></div>
            <div class="radio-jquery-ui">@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsElite, "true") <label>Расширенная</label></div>
           </div>
    </div>
    <div class="NumberedRow three">
        3.
        <div class="cnt">
             Введите срок
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumDays)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="itog">
        Итого: <span id="ïtogo">0 рублей 00 копеек</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Купить"/>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Model:

```
public class BuyModel
{
    public string PaymentSystem;
    public bool IsElite;
    public int NumDays;
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PaymentSystems;
}
```

Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Buy(BuyModel model)
    {
        return View("BuySummary", model);
    }
```

And when I submit it the model.IsElite is always false(as by default). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: looks perfect. that always sux. I suspect it's fine, but share your model and action method.

Comment: You should bind to the properties not variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
public bool IsElite;
```

with

```
public bool IsElite {get;set;}
```

It has to work now !

Remember to bind to the `properties`and not the variables

Comment: Omg! Thank You! Im coding with Mvc for a plenty amount of time already and never made such a mistake... Maybe it time to go to sleep o.O

Answer (score 0):

like this. ? 
 you need to set a property for that

```
   public bool IsElite{get;set;};
```

then try like this

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsElite, "True", model.IsElite== true ? new { Checked = "checked" } : null)
```